# Graph disconnected error when trying to extract features from inceptionv3 architecture

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to extract some features from the middle of the architecture and use it for another model.

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
input_tensor = Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))  # Input shape for InceptionV3
InceptionA_feature_extractor = models.Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=base_model.get_layer('mixed2').output)
```

While trying to do this, I am getting the following error, what could be the possible reasons?

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_6'), name='input_6', description="created by layer 'input_6'") at layer "conv2d_376". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering, "Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for KerasTensor," suggests that there's an issue with the connectivity of the layers in your model.

To resolve this issue, make sure that you correctly connect the input tensor to the layers in your model by visualizing  the graph with *tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_dtype=True)*.

It will be help to find disconnected parts of the graph or errors in the model architecture.